# Generating Unique Random number JAVA

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get shuffle character from String Question. But the character is repeated.

Random Method

```
public ArrayList<Integer> Random(int length) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        return list;
    }
```

MainActivity

```
    strQuestion = c.getString("question");
    int length = strQuestion.length();
    str_buff.getChars(0, length, char_text, 0);

 for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            int k = Random(length).get(i);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(char_text[k]));
                tv.setId(k);
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
                layout.addView(tv);
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to shuffle the string as an arraylist and convert it back into a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you are asking, you want to create a new TextView for each of the letters in the string "question" but you want them created in random order?

What you have written now creates a new "random" `ArrayList` for each iteration of the for loop in MainActivity. I think you want to move your call to Random(length) outside the for loop. The for loop in MainActivity should look something like this...

```
ArrayList<Integer> randomized = Random(length);
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            int k = randomized.get(i);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(char_text[k]));
                tv.setId(k);
                tv.setTextSize(30);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tv.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
                layout.addView(tv);
        }
```

Note: if the string you assign to strQuestion has repeating letters in it (ex. "banana"), you will need to modify your method if you only want unique letters outputted in your TextViews.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a different shuffle on each iteration of the for-loop. A given element will typically appear at different positions in different shuffles, so you can see it multiple times.

Create one shuffled list outside the loop instead.